# Terraform AWS secret manager valueFrom syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

Im trying to provision a service on ECS using Terraform.
I have secrets in AWS Secrets Manager:

```
{
   "test": "secret"
}
```

and provide them to my task definition as follows:

```
 ....
 "secrets": ${jsonencode(
   [
     {
       name = "test_1",
       valueFrom = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:....../test"
     }
   ]
  ....
```

When I deploy my container, it complains that `ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret`, which makes sense, because such an ARN does not exist. If I drop `/test` on the end, however, I get `test_1 = {"test": "secret"}` in my environment, which is ok but not what I want - I want just `secret`. Thats how it works in examples that I have seen, like for instance here - https://www.chakray.com/creating-fargate-ecs-task-aws-using-terraform/

What am I missing?

Comment: You are not missing anything, what you want is simply not really possible. You get the secret value and that's it, if you not want it to be a json don't store it as a json, the secret parameter value can simply be `secret` instead of `{"test": "secret"}`.

Comment: ah. the way AWS prompts the values is a bit misleading. This should be the answer.

Comment: I'm not using Terraform, but creating a task within AWS Console. I've tried `arn:aws:secretsmanager:......:test::` (note the double colons) and it worked for me. For details please see [amazon ecs - AWS ECS - How to retrieve specific key from secret manager? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57191835).

Comment: In addition, `arn:aws:ssm:<region>:<aws_account_id>:parameter/<parameter_name>` (from the blog post you mentioned) is a Systems Manager Parameter syntax, you should not mix it with Secrets Manager. Please see [Specifying sensitive data using Systems Manager Parameter Store - Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-parameters.html).

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you're looking to use a single key from a secret (which holds a key value pair)

The syntax for `valueFrom` is

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:secret-name:json-key:version-stage:version-id
```

For easier understanding, you can assume like

```
"${your_secrets.arn}:${keyname}::"
```

For example, if your secretname is `prod-db-credentials` with value

```
{ "username": "dbuser", "password": "dbpass" }
```

Then your task definition should be like

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-2:222000000036:secret:prod-db-credentials-vXXXXC:username::"
    }]
  }]
}
```

For more information, you can refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html#secrets-envvar